# First Derivative of MFCC Coefficients in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, feature-extraction, audio-processing, mfcc

I have extracted mel frequency cepstral coefficient (MFCC) features (in Matlab) for some speech classification. I'm currently thinking of adding the first and second derivatives of MFCC coefficient features. How can we get first and second derivatives from the MFCC?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mfcc method like this:

`[coeffs,delta,deltaDelta] = mfcc(audioIn,fs);`

Where **coeffs** is a vector containing the main features obtained using mfcc function, **delta** is a vector with the first derivatives, **deltaDelta** is also a vector with the second derivatives, **audioIn** is the audio you want to extract features, and **fs** is the sampling frequency.

You can find the documentation here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/mfcc.html